# Cache previous search for JSON updated hourly

Tags: php, caching

I have a service that pulls from a weather API which only allows me to call it 500 times a day as I can't find any good free weather APIs that have hourly data. The service calls the api which returns a JSON array everytime the user hits the page as of right now.

Since I'm the only one using the service currently that is not a problem but for future I was hoping to cache search results and have them expire after an hour or two as the data just change rather frequently.

So if a user types in the their zip that result would be cached for 2 hours. If they pressed refresh it would pull the saved data from the cache or if another user came in and type the same zip it would pull from the cache.

What is the best way to cut down on the total API requests? I thought about using SQL but it seems it wouldn't be a good fit since the data is somewhat dynamic and there are many different possibilities over 50,000+ zips.

Comment: since it limit 500 calls a day, you won't have a chance to serve 50k of different zip

Comment: I would be interested to know if there are any other solutions then storing the request zip along with the response in a sql table. I have done something similar with SQL for credit score requests, but they are cached for X number of days. If the user requests a credit score for a user within X number of days, we do not hit the external API, we simply pull from the SQL server DB.

Comment: @ajreal I know... I was making a point that I need data is dynamic and I can just stuff it into one Sql table.

Comment: @jame31rock The site does a calculation that is based upon the current weather which is updated frequently so I'm not sure if that would be a good fit in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a SQL database?

This seems fairly straight forward.  The one thing to keep in mind, is to capture as much information as possible on each API call.  If the API allows you to fetch more than just one piece of information at a time, fetch as much as you can so you don't have to go back to the API.

**Note:** This solution does not get around the fact that you can only go to the API 500 times.  It will simply provide a way for you to not have to go back to the API more than once per zip code.

1. Take in the zip code
2. Check your database to see if you already have that zip stored (if you do, check the timestamp to see if you want to go to the API for newer information)
3. If it's not in your database, place your API call and store the returned info in the database using the Zip as the identifying data

Comment: I did this, thank you. Hopefully it will stretch those 500 requests out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd prepare a table with the following fields: `request_sig`, `response_data`, `timestamp`.

Here's the "algorithm" I'd follow:

1. User requests weather info.
2. Take API call parameters "giveMeWeather.com`/zip/10001`" and hash them.
3. Check the database for that hash (the `sig`), if I find a match => return the `response_data`.
4. If I don't find a match, call your API and store the response in the database then serve the response to the clinet.
5. Have a `cronjob` cleaning the table and delete old entries (check the `timestamp` for old entries).

This won't solve the 500 calls limitation, but it's a chaching solution.

Comment: What's the purpose of convoluting things by hashing the request signature? If you know that the user is only entering the zip code for searches, you can simply use that for the table key.

Comment: @Blake, **IF** the only criteria is the ZIP code, but the API might offer the possibility to get data for a time in the past, or forecast next week for example, maybe get data in C or F. So you can blindly hash the request string and not worry about it _or_ you can think about each and every parameter and update your caching code every time you add a new search criteria.

Comment: Then you can very easily run the risk of going over the 500 request limit by have intersecting requests that could be easily served by a single API call, and the request limit seems like the OP's primary concern.

Comment: @tubaguy50035, the caching is agnostic to the type of the request; request historic data, forecast or current, C or F, for a ZIP code or other location information.

Comment: @Blake, and how's using ZIP codes instead of signatures (hashes or others) would help? as far as we know, he might have 501 unique visitors requesting info about 501 ZIP codes. In this case he **must** call the API 501 times, there's no way around it. OP requested a caching solution, I posted a caching solution (I've also noted in the answer itself that this won't solve the 500 limit problem, it's a caching solution)

Comment: @tubaguy50035, it's 00:30, I have to wake up early so I won't argue with you. So, OP, don't use hashes. and by the way, good job deleting your comment after I replied.

Comment: @Adnan Simply using zip codes won't intrinsically fix anything, but if you're parsing the resulting data properly you can avoid unnecessary API calls. Visitor A requests a 10-day forecast and 5-day forecast from the API. That's 2 API calls for the price of one if you're taking careful stock of the resulting data.

Comment: @Blake, what about the case I proposed in my comment? `he might have 501 unique visitors requesting info about 501 ZIP codes`, what's your solution?

Comment: @Adnan Obviously there is no workaround to that, but at least parsing the data properly nets him 500 **valuable** API calls.

Comment: @Adnan For the record, your solution is adequate; the OP just seemed more concerned with the API call limit than anything else.

Answer (score -2):

There are a lot of caching systems available. You can specify how long you want data cached, and you can give each section of saved data its own key. Some are memcached, APC, and XCache. I'm not sure specifically whether they use a database, files, or what to cache.

Comment: You're not sure if those caches use a database?  How is this helpful?